# Python AsyncIO within MultiProcessing Processes

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create two processes that run forever, each running an asyncio loop inside of them.

I want to understand if the logic is correct. Is there a better way to do the same thing?

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing


async def my_async_func(topic):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(topic)


def create_aio_loop(topic):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(my_async_func(topic), loop=loop)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.stop()


def main():
    topic_a = 'New to Asyncio'
    topic_b = 'New to Multiprocessing'
    process_a = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_aio_loop, args=(topic_a, ))
    process_b = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_aio_loop, args=(topic_b, ))
    processes = [process_a, process_b]

    try:
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for process in processes:
            process.terminate()
            process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: have you looked at aiomultiprocess? It's a package aimed at what you are doing. Here is a link: https://aiomultiprocess.omnilib.dev/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to create two processes that run forever, each running an asyncio loop inside of them.

I assume that you know why you wish to dispatch some of your code on several processing (virtual) cores (multiprocessing) and paralellize the rest on the same core (asyncio).

Then I think that you did right: you spawn two processes, and each of them has its own asyncio loop. The only improvement that I could find was to use `loop.run_until_complete`, which removes one line of code :) :

```
import os
import asyncio
import multiprocessing

async def my_async_func(topic):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(topic)


def create_aio_loop(topic):
    process_name = "[Process %s, topic %s]" % (os.getpid(), topic)
    print("%s Started " % process_name)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(my_async_func(topic))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("%s Loop interrupted" % process_name)
        loop.stop()

    print("%s terminating" % process_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    topic_a = 'New to Asyncio'
    topic_b = 'New to Multiprocessing'
    process_a = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_aio_loop, args=(topic_a, ))
    process_b = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_aio_loop, args=(topic_b, ))
    processes = [process_a, process_b]

    try:
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for process in processes:
            process.terminate()
            process.join()
```

Oh and also I suggest that you display all messages using a prefix containing the process id, that is much easier for multiprocessing debugging. I introduced an example with the start/terminate print messages.

Running this yields:

```
>python tmp_asyncio.py
[Process 11456, topic New to Multiprocessing] Started
[Process 18396, topic New to Asyncio] Started
New to Asyncio
New to Multiprocessing

(here I pressed Ctrl+C)

[Process 11456, topic New to Multiprocessing] Loop interrupted
[Process 11456, topic New to Multiprocessing] terminating
[Process 18396, topic New to Asyncio] Loop interrupted
[Process 18396, topic New to Asyncio] terminating
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\baseenv\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 310, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\baseenv\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\baseenv\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 81, in wait
    res = _winapi.WaitForSingleObject(int(self._handle), msecs)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually have been experiencing the atexit._run_exitfuncs error. It's a good idea to prefix the print with PID so I can try debugging. Thanks for suggestion; didn't occur to me. Will post if I could find a solution. cheers!